# ajax post request js to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've been trying to make an ajax post request to send a js array to a php file, so i tried and after many attempts i finally succeded. But i need to make an sql call with php (which i know how to do) to compare the values fetched with the array and print the corresponding values in html tags inside the body... However i found out that my php script is printing anything above itself plus the value taken, so i can't place it where i want in the body.
I really don't know why this happens.
Here's the scripts:
cartscript.js:

```
let elements_div = document.querySelector('.cart_elements');
let cart_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("added_elements")); 

$(document).ready(() => {
  $.ajax({
    url: "cart.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { values: JSON.stringify(cart_array) },
    success: (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

and here's cart.php:

```
<?php
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['values'])) {
  $values = json_decode($_POST['values']);

  foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo $value . "\n";
  }

  exit;
}
?>
//rest of the html code...
//i want to print the values here in the middle
```

I'm using a xampp local server,
Hope you guys can land me a hand fixing this ^^. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"my php script is printing anything above itself plus the value taken"* - It's not clear to me what you mean by that.  What is the value of `response` in your AJAX `success` callback and how does it differ from what you expect?  If the same PHP script is returning a mix of JSON and HTML then it sounds like what you want is to separate it into different PHP scripts.

Comment: The script you make an ajax call to is like a subroutine that returns one result. First you should consider returning JSON as well as receiving it. Second you should make only one response to the call, so once you have done the `echo $someJson;`  you exit the script. You should not be and there should be no reason to return any HTML unless it is part of the JSON response

Comment: PS You do an `exit;` so nothing will be done after the exit is executed anyway

Comment: You have 2 options to do what I think you want to do. 1. query the database and return a json array of rows from your query. Then in the js you create the html by processing the row data and plug it into the existing page. OR 2. You make the PHP generate the html you want on the page and return that as either on big text BLOB or as a piece of JSON for the js to place on the page

Comment: BTW, you don't need `$_POST &&` in the `if` condition.

Comment: As an aside: `data: { values: JSON.stringify(cart_array) },`...this is a bit silly really. Why are you wrapping JSON data inside form-url-encoded data (which is what jquery converts your data object to when it sends the request)? Having two different data formats complicates things, doesn't add any value, and can sometimes cause issues with encoding etc.

Comment: If you want to send JSON, just send JSON: e.g. `$.ajax({ url: "cart.php", type: "post", data: JSON.stringify(cart_array), contentType: "application/json"` ...and then read that JSON in PHP with `$values = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: `i can't place it where i want in the body`...why, where do you need to put it, and why? It shouldn't matter. As mentioned earlier, it's often better if you separate PHP code which deals with AJAX requests into a separate PHP script anyway, so it only handles that one task specifically. Then you have better code encapsulation (you're on your way to an API, in fact!) and there's no danger of it getting mixed up with other functionality and accidentally returning stray HTML etc from elsewhere in the same file, along with the intended content.

Comment: Ah I see. now your comment... `//i want to print the values here in the middle`...you seem to have misunderstood how AJAX works. AJAX does not refresh your entire page. It sends the request to the server, and anything PHP outputs is passed back to the Javascript code which sent the request. It does not update the rest of your page automatically, unlike when you follow a link or post a regular form. If you want to make changes to your page based on data the AJAX request returned, you need to write some JavaScript code in your "success" function to achieve that.